# How to unlock or restore Safari

Tags: safari, mojave

One day my Safari got blocked. I doesn't allow me to close it, or even to change the URL, neither interact with the website. As you can see in the image bellow most of the menu options appear disabled.

I tried to force quit with the Activity Monitor, but when reopening Safari, is on the same state.

Is there a way to reset/reinstall Safari different to reinstall the system?

For more information, I'm using Mojave and Safari has no extensions installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the system, as other answers suggest, is always a painful option.

I actually found by chance the solution to my problem. And it was:

> **opening Safari pressing the Shift ⇧ key**.

That opens Safari without restoring Tabs and Windows. So it was my session Tab or Window what was in an error state causing the browser to be blocked. Just clearing previous session that way magically returned the Safari to a normal state.
I got the idea from [here](https://www.chriswrites.com/open-safari-without-restoring-tabs-and-windows-quick-tip/)

Answer (score 2):

Try Force Quitting Safari (either Activity Monitor or  (Apple) > Force Quit) and then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the dock icon to open Safari. This should fix your issue.

Comment: tks for share tips

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the system drops a new functional system and then migrates all user data and settings in place, so you don't lose anything.

If no one has a more surgical fix, I would boot to recovery (Internet Recovery is a nice option if you have somewhat new to new hardware) and you don't have a USB installer handy. You can of course download the installer and make a local installer from the App Store, but recovery is the recommended way to fix this and other issues where a system framework or critical app like Safari gets broken.

-

Before you reinstall:

- Have you verified that making a new user account (System Preferences) and logging in there is still broken?
- Have you also verified this doesn't resolve itself after a restart?

If it's not the system, you will have wasted time reinstalling and have to fix your preferences / settings if that's causing safari to break. It's less likely, but I've seen user corruption cause this on occasion.

There's no harm in trying recovery first, just these might save you time if you are not keen to reinstall for any reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Clear all website data first. Malicious software can make uses of your browser cache and cookies to escalate access of your OS . And then restore the Mac OS . That reinstalls everything